# Add media (mp3, mp4) to iTunes from an App - Is Podcast only option?

Tags: iphone, itunes, core-audio, podcast

I am making an app for a Band.
We would like to offer 'special content' to app users.
(song - mp3 or video (mp4))

We would like to allow the End Users to download & keep this content (not stream it each time)

What are options for this?

1) Wrap as a PodCast? (Simple, Available outside of App - but in 'Postcasts' - not 'Music')

2) Deliver as CoreAudio? Use AVAudioPlayer? (Complex, only Available inside of App)

**3) Any way to get a Song/Album into iTunes-Music area from an App?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple seems to allow you access to play items, and query iPod asset metadata, but doesn't seem to allow your application to import directly.

However:

You could add an "openURL" for your iTunes song - i.e. the "itms:" URL (which evokes iTunes)  - which would effectivley have your application lanuch iTunes and go to the "purchase" screen of the [free] song. Clicking a button would use an action like:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/mysongsurlinthestore"]];
```